# Log changed values Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

I want to create one database table (with fields: `newValue`, `oldValue`, `changedTable`, `changedField`, `changedDate`, `user`) to log any changes made in any database table. How can I track those Values?

I've read about Envers-Hibernate which could do something like that, but using this means to create one database tables for every table I want to track and not one for all.

Working with an AuditInterceptor (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) does not work because I cannot log the old value anymore.

Does anyone know a solution for this Problem?

Comment: You can get access to old value from the method `onFlushDirty`  through the `previousState` parameter.

Comment: I know your question is with regard to Hibernate, but have you considered using database triggers ?